# Fetching GRPC request and response header using Golang

Tags: go, grpc

Trying to extract GRPC request and response header using golang language.
Is there any way to extract the headers.

Comment: Are you still having this issue? Please explain what exactly you need. The question isn't explained enough.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the metadata

client-unary:

```
var header, trailer metadata.MD // variable to store header and trailer
r, err := client.SomeRPC(
    ctx,
    someRequest,
    grpc.Header(&header),    // will retrieve header
    grpc.Trailer(&trailer),  // will retrieve trailer
)

// do something with header and trailer
```

server:
Metadata can be retrieved from context using FromIncomingContext:

```
func (s *server) SomeRPC(ctx context.Context, in *pb.SomeRequest) (*pb.SomeResponse, err) {
    md, ok := metadata.FromIncomingContext(ctx)
    // do something with metadata
}
```

client-stream:

```
stream, err := client.SomeStreamingRPC(ctx)

// retrieve header
header, err := stream.Header()

// retrieve trailer
trailer := stream.Trailer()
```

source:
https://github.com/grpc/grpc-go/blob/master/Documentation/grpc-metadata.md#unary-call

Comment: in this" grpc.Header(&header),    // will retrieve header
    grpc.Trailer(&trailer)," how to print the header and trailer

Comment: The values will be put into header and tailer. After the call you can access the values of header and trailer. You could print them with fmt.Printf("%#v %#v", header, trailer)

Comment: I am getting this printing.2019/08/29 16:54:39 Response from server: bar
2019/08/29 16:54:39 metadata.MD{"content-type":[]string{"application/grpc"}} metadata.MD{} ,where as my requriement is it should be the request url and response URL.The requirement is it should print request URL as "POST /xxx/hhhh and response status is "status 200Ok"

Comment: Yeah, that's all the headers that came back from the gRPC server you made the call to. Exactly what you asked for?

Comment: Can anybody help me ? Not able to find a way to extract request url and response URL .

Comment: metadata.MD{":authority":[]string{"localhost:7777"}, "content-type":[]string{"application/grpc"}, "user-agent":[]string{"grpc-go/1.23.0-dev"}}.. Its not printing the path,schema all other headers received at server end. Any help

Comment: why do you need that? that's all standardized and gRPC exists so you don't need to care for all that. the schema can be shared via the proto files that you are using to generate your stub. from that you create client- & server-stubs and they handle all schemas and paths for you.